# Use Partial Class In Ef 7 Migration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, migration

How can I add properties from the Main project to the Domain project's `OrderItem`? I tried adding a CS file directly in the main project, but migration gave me an error saying

> [InverseProperty] attribute on property 'OrderItem.Order' is not
> valid.
>
> The property OrderItems is not a valid navigation on the related type
> Order. Ensure that the property exists and is a valid reference or
> collection navigation.

Here are the details:

In the Domain project, I have a class named `OrderItem`. I want to add some properties from the Main project to `OrderItem` as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

[image]

The code in the Domain project's `OrderItem` class is:

```
namespace Domain.Orders;
[Table("Table_34")]
public partial class OrderItem : BaseEntity
{
    [Column("Field_09")]
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
    [Column("Field_10", TypeName = "decimal(18, 0)")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [Column("Field_11")]
    public long ProductItemId { get; set; }
    [Column("Field_12", TypeName = "decimal(18, 0)")]
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    [Column("Field_13", TypeName = "decimal(18, 0)")]
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    [Column("Field_14")]
    [ForeignKey("Field_14")]
    public long OrderId { get; set; }
    [Column("Field_15")]
    public int Count { get; set; }
    [Column("Field_16", TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    [Column("Field_17")]
    public long? Time { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("OrderItems")]
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

In the Main project, I have another partial class named `OrderItem` like this:

```
namespace Domain.Orders;
public partial class OrderItem
{
    [InverseProperty("OrderItem")]
    public License License { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("OrderItem")]
    public RequestLicense RequestLicense { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can't have partial class parts in different assemblies.

Comment: But I need this

Comment: Well, you can't. There are probably many other ways to do this, but we can't give any advice without knowing how things work in your solution, esp. how/where these objects are created. Besides that, IMO "Domain" is a misnomer. It looks like a project that contains the Entity-Framework classes, which would make it a data access library, not a domain. The classes in the main project look more like domain classes and domain classes should not have a dependency on EF. They should be created from the data access classes and in that process receive data for `License` and `RequestLicense`.

Comment: I added more Information But MY solution was To see My structure
any advice Will be okay And i Change My Naming

Comment: I changed my Structure To Inherit for Main OrderItem And Added Child To Context 
This Works Fine

Answer (score 0):

Partial classes are used to define separate parts of a class **in the same assembly**.

If `License` and `RequestLicense` are truly parts of your Domain then those properties should exist on the `OrderItem` itself in your Domain project.

If, however, you intend to use OrderItem in different contexts and the concepts of `License` and `RequestLicense` are additional properties that only apply in certain contexts, then you might want to store those separately.

The DDD way would be to have two microservices (each would have it's own DbContext and migrations):

1. **Orders**, which includes `Order`, `OrderItem` and `OrderComment`.  This service would be used for managing core Order details.
2. **Licensing**, which includes `License` and `RequestLicense`  This service would be used for managing licensing of order items.

In the **Licensing** service, you'd store the Ids of the related OrderItems (and a copy of any OrderItem properties that are necessary for Licensing to complete its job).

Comment: I had thought about this, but I wanted to know the best way to do it